# How do you monitor MariaDB SSL expiration for both replication and client certificates?

Tags: mysql, ssl, mariadb, prometheus, percona

There are a number of tools for monitoring SSL expiration for services available via HTTPS, e.g. we use https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter to receive alerts when SSL certificates expire in <14 days on both internal and external services.

We use Percona's XtraDB cluster (i.e. MariaDB) with SSL for both front-end and replication traffic. The *relevant* configuration is shown below:

```
$ less /etc/mysql/percona-xtradb-cluster.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
[mysqld]
pxc_encrypt_cluster_traffic=ON
ssl-ca=/etc/ssl/xtradb_server_ca.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/ssl/xtradb_server_cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/ssl/xtradb_server_key.pem

[client]
ssl-ca=/etc/ssl/xtradb_server_ca.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/ssl/xtradb_server_cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/ssl/xtradb_server_key.pem
```

What we have yet to figure out: **How do you monitor the SSL expiration for certificates loaded by `mysqld.service`?**

We use Ansible to deploy new certificates and perform rolling-restarts of `mysqld.service` on each host, however it would be great to monitor and confirm that these certificates are being properly updated.

Is there a common solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no server variable or API function available to determine the validation period of a server certificate.

A simple workaround would be (assuming secure_file_priv is not set) :

```
$ mysql -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ssl_cert'"
+---------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                      |
+---------------+----------------------------+
| ssl_cert      | /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem |
+---------------+----------------------------+
$ mysql  -e "SELECT LOAD_FILE('/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem')\G" > server-cert.pem
$ openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in ./server-cert.pem
notAfter=Jan 22 10:11:10 2021 GMT
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, taught me something. It doesn't _completely_ solve the problem, e.g. this only confirms that the `/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem` file has been updated (which running Ansible should guarantee), but not that MySQL has actually loaded the content from the latest file. Interesting to learn that no server variable or API function exists. Thinking on it further: perhaps comparing `mysql.service` uptime and the file's timestamp is a _decent_ solution?

Comment: Since the question is tagged with mariadb: No need to restart if a new certificate was installed. Instead use `FLUSH SSL`.

Comment: Thanks Georg, that's very helpful and I wasn't previously aware.

Answer (score 2):

A solution was shared with me offline, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/ssltls-status-variables/!

MariaDB has variables which display SSL expiration information:

```
mysql> show status like 'ssl_server_not%';
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
| Variable_name         | Value                    |
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
| Ssl_server_not_after  | May 24 11:46:23 2020 GMT |
| Ssl_server_not_before | Feb 24 11:46:23 2020 GMT |
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'll update this solution once I've figured out how to either

1. Expose these as metrics via https://github.com/prometheus/mysqld_exporter (opened [mysqld_exporter/issues/457](https://github.com/prometheus/mysqld_exporter/issues/457))
2. Query for the variables via https://github.com/free/sql_exporter

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.